# Helm chart MongoDb cannot create directory permisions

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I try to deploy mongodb with helm and it gives this error:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory /bitnami/mongodb/data : permision denied.
```

I also tried this solution:

```
sudo chown -R 1001 /tmp/mongo
```

but it says no this directory.

Answer (score 1):

You have permission denied on `/bitnami/mongodb/data` and you are trying to modify another path: `/tmp/mongo`. It is possible that you do not have such a directory at all.
You need to change the owner of the resource for which you don't have permissions, not random (non-related) paths :)

You've probably seen  [this github issue](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mongodb/issues/177) and  this answer:

> You are getting that error message because the container can't mount the /tmp/mongo directory you specified in the docker-compose.yml file.
>
> As you can see in  [our changelog](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mongodb#366-r16-and-411-r9), the container was migrated to the non-root user approach, that means that the user  `1001`  needs read/write permissions in the /tmp/mongo folder so it can be mounted and used. Can you modify the permissions in your local folder and try to launch the container again?

```
sudo chown -R 1001 /tmp/mongo
```

This method will work if you are going to mount the `/tmp/mongo` folder, which is actually not quite a common behavior. Look for another answer:

> Please note that mounting host path volumes is not the usual way to work with these containers. If using docker-compose, it would be using docker volumes (which already handle the permission issue), the same would apply with Kubernetes and the MongoDB helm chart, which would use the `securityContext` section to ensure the proper permissions.

In your situation, you'll just have change owner to the path `/bitnami/mongodb/data` or to use [Security Context](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/) on your Helm chart and everything should work out for you.

Probably [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#configure-volume-permission-and-ownership-change-policy-for-pods) you can find the most interesting part with example context:

```yaml
securityContext:
  runAsUser: 1000
  runAsGroup: 3000
  fsGroup: 2000
  fsGroupChangePolicy: "OnRootMismatch"
```